# Import terrain from Sketchup to Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, sketchup

I imported Google Map terrain into the Sketchup, according to the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZE6lOXsrbbA).

[image]

How can I import this terrain from Sketchup to Unity3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your model as .fbx file, then just paste it to unity.

Remember to apply rot loc scale (i'm more blender oriented, but i belive works same in sketchup) to avoid any weird behaviours of the model, after imported to unity